# Import ML Kit dependencies on iOS

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/ios) documentation to implement ML Kit for iOS, but I can't figure out which import should I use to create a VisionImage.

The pod I am using is `GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning`.

I have tried with the following imports without luck:

```
import MLImage
import MLKit
import MLKitBarcodeScanning
```

Which is the right import to create a VisionImage and then a BarcodeScanner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MLKit Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/release-notes#ios-api-latest-versions) (as of **June 29, 2021**), the correct pod artifact names are listed like this.
[image]

---

Update your pod declaration to the latest version like this.

```
pod 'MLKitBarcodeScanning', '1.3.0'
```

After this change, do a `pod install` and now you can use following two imports to work with `MLKit` on iOS.

```
import MLKitBarcodeScanning
import MLKitVision
```

Answer (score 0):

At top of the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/ios) you referenced, there is a link to the [ML Kit quickstart sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/ios/quickstarts/vision), where you can find sample code in both Swift and Objective-C showing you how to import ML Kit.  Specifically, in Swift you can `import MLKit` and in Objective-C `@import MLKit;`.

Comment: As I have written in my original post, I have already tried `import MLKit` and it's not working. I have also tried the sample project and it doesn't work there as well.

Comment: Please provide the full sequence of steps you took when trying the sample project (starting from "git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit.git"...) and the exact error when it didn't work for you.